# Laravel 4 Controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel-4, controller

I just want to know if it is ok to create a constructor in my PostController?

Example 1:

```
public class PostController extends BaseController
{
   protected $posts;

    //Is this ok?
   public function __construct(Post $posts){
        $this->posts = $posts;
     }

   public function getPosts(){

      $posts = $this->posts->all();

      return View::make('get-index',compact('posts'))

  }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you think it shouldn't be? Though `$this->posts = $posts;` in your constructor is pointless

Comment: You can indeed use constructors. However, Laravel likes to use something called dependency injection to initialise the controller. You should add a parameter to your controller's constructor like this: `public function __construct(Post $post) {`

Comment: Of course i forgot to give it Post obj as param :)

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to use constructor in your Controller. You can leverage Laravel's Dependency Injection and IoC Container so your application will be more test-able and easy to maintain.

Taylor has made a great explanation about DI and IoC container. You can watch following videos for detailed information :

1. http://vimeo.com/53009943
2. http://vimeo.com/53029232